# Create hidden field element for each drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach

I know this is a similar question to my previous one however its slightly different.

I have this script adding each 'dropped' element to a list. Now i need it adding into a variable / hidden field so i can pass it to the next page via a form.

When i run it at the moment. It alerts for each one however, it does it not just for every item dropped but if there are 10 items dropped it will run 10 times per item droped rather than once per item dropped.

Any help would be great.

```
//Record and add dropped items to list
            var txt = $("#listbox");
            var dtstart = copiedEventObject.start + '\n'
            var caltitle = copiedEventObject.title

            var txt = $('#listbox');     
            txt.append("<li class ='listItem'> "+dtstart +"</li>")

            var listItems = $('.listItem'); 

                $('#calendarform').submit(function() {

                        listItems.each(function(){   //For each event do this:

                            alert( listItems.text() );                  

                        });

                    return false;

                });

            // remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();
```

Comment: So, each time you drop an item it runs a separate `submit` event for each item?

Comment: he's adding a submit handler to the form in that code, not submitting every time, but he is adding a submit handler each drop

Comment: it could be that? but if i move the submit out of the drop it doesnt appear to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem lies in this code

```
listItems.each(function(){  //For each event do this:
    alert( listItems.text() );                  
});
```

you are alerting the text of all the list items for each list item.

use jQuery(this) to access the current item within an each block

```
listItems.each(function(){   //For each event do this:
    alert( $(this).text() );                  
});
```

Assuming your code is within a drop event handler, you are also adding a submit handler each time you drop.  This means that each time you drop, you queue up *another* submit event.  This is probably not desired.  Move this submit(function(){}) block outside your drop handler to prevent it from firing that function more than once.

```
$('#calendarform').submit(function(e) {
    var listItems = $('.listItem'); 
    listItems.each(function(){   //For each event do this:
        alert( listItems.text() );                  
    });
    e.preventDefault();//stop normal behavior
    return false;

});
```

and to create elements on the fly you just pass jQuery the html, and `append` it to your form.

```
$('<input type="hidden" name="listItem[]"/>').appendTo("#calendarForm").val(listItem.text())
```

you may have to fiddle with the name element to get it to submit as an array in your server side language, but you're also within an `each` loop, which provides you with an index, so you can do the following.

```
$('#calendarform').submit(function(e) {
        var form = $(this);
        var listItems = $('.listItem'); 
        listItems.each(function(index){   //For each event do this:
            var listItem = $(this);
            $("<input type='hidden'/>").val(listItem.text()).appendTo(form).attr('name', 'listItem[' + index + ']');
        });
        e.preventDefault();//stop normal behavior
        return false;

    });
```

Comment: hmm. that seems to do the same thing.

Comment: when i place the submit handler anywhere else it submits the form but doesnt show an alert and ignores the return false.

Comment: @ChrisTill I've updated my answer with some sample event handler for you.  Chances are your `listItems` obj was undefined or something, which is why no items were alerted.  I've moved your selector inside the submit handler.

Comment: That works great. Now, the last part. I dont need an alert, rather to put each of that data into variables that i can pass and collect on the response page.

Comment: Perfect. Now i can just pull those from the array with php im guessing?

Comment: they should get put into the $_POST['listItem'] variable, which should get bound as an array

Comment: Is it possible to put multiple values into this? I.e. the date and title for each event?